# Cannot commit on Junos

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I am learning Junos. I applied the following command on my switch:

```
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm> configure
Entering configuration mode
The configuration has been changed but not committed

{master:3}[edit]
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm# set interfaces ge-1/0/44 unit 0 description "ydedc1-INFREP01- DC1 R1-R13 (PP 389)"

{master:3}[edit]
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm# set interfaces ge-1/0/44 unit 0 family ethernet-switching

{master:3}[edit]
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm# set vlans MTNC_ALOM interface ge-1/0/44.0
```

When I proceed to "commit-ing" I get the following:

```
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm# commit
error: Access interface <ge-1/0/44.0> has more than one vlan member: mtnc_os and MTNC_ALOM
error: configuration check-out failed

{master:3}[edit]
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm#
```

**What can I do to remove the existing vlan so that I can save the new configuration I need?**
Below is the **"show interface"**

```
hw_tanyu_n@yamsc-a-DC-R1R13-asw-1.cm> show interfaces ge-1/0/44  
Physical interface: ge-1/0/44, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 319, SNMP ifIndex: 663  
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, Speed: Auto, Duplex: Auto, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled,  
  Source filtering: Disabled, Flow control: Enabled, Auto-negotiation: Enabled, Remote fault: Online  
  Device flags   : Present Running  
  Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0  
  Link flags     : None  
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues  
  Current address: 00:26:88:6a:53:2f, Hardware address: 00:26:88:6a:53:2f  
  Last flapped   : 2016-04-25 16:56:01 WAT (16:16:11 ago)  
  Input rate     : 504 bps (0 pps)  
  Output rate    : 504 bps (0 pps)  
  Active alarms  : None  
  Active defects : None  
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled  

  Logical interface ge-1/0/44.0 (Index 181) (SNMP ifIndex 280)  
    Description: connected to ESXDR-DB Service Console (10.67.53.14/24) on Patch_0389  
    Flags: SNMP-Traps 0x0 Encapsulation: ENET2  
    Bandwidth: 0  
    Input packets : 21  
    Output packets: 20761  
    Protocol eth-switch  
      Flags: None  

{master:3}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have the VLAN mtnc_os configured on the interface as well.
When you add the MTNC_ALOM VLAN it is added to the vlan list. Your port is probably an access port and can only have one VLAN configured.
Try to reconfigure your port to a trunk port or remove the existing VLAN before comitting.
Paste the output of "show interfaces ge-1/0/44" if that does not help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Please could you help me with the command to remove the existing vlan? I have edited my question with the **show interfaces ge-1/0/44** command

Comment: Without knowing which device you are using, and based on the commands above, the command would be `delete vlans mntc_os interface ge-1/0/44.0`.  JunOS uses the delete command to remove the highest-nested command specified.  Thus `delete vlans mntc_os` would remove the entire vlan from the config, but `delete vlans mntc_os interface ge-1/0/44.0` removes just that interface from the vlan.

Answer (score 0):

you have one more than solution to solve this problem ..one of them code here delete interfaces ge-1/0/44 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan..we deleted all vlan on interface after we can add vlan on interface ge-1/0/44...
as you can see that   set interface ge-1/0/44 unit 0 family ethernet switching vlan member ...(vlan id example 20)

you cant delete vlan before remove existing vlan on interface

Answer (score 0):

I always use a commit-check when im doing any sort of commit operation it will help in these situations. That is just quick advice I am also fairly new to being a Juniper Network engineer most of my previous experience was heavy Cisco/Aruba/checkpoint/palo.

If you haven't started reading it already....make sure you put it at the top of your list

https://www.juniper.net/assets/us/en/local/pdf/study-guide/study-guide-jncia.pdf

It is the JNCIA manual, free on Juniper's site and contains a wealth of great information you will need to be successful.

Best,

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `commit check` would give the exact same error message as a regular `commit` would have.

Comment: To expound on my answer, check is a good policy and you are correct wouldnt resolve this...you are currently trying to commit an access port with multiple VLANs, or an "untagged" port in juniper speak. This needs to be trunked or part of an irb in order for it to function properly. Access ports are used for connection to hosts, which doesnt generally ential multiple vlans due to NIC limitations in end devices. NIC devices in hosts. Laptop and desktop machines are not good with 802.1Q....configure this as a trunk port and add both vlans as allowed on the trunk. This should resolve this, cheers